# Most stable isobar for even-$A$ nuclei

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements, isotopes

In the Liquid Drop Model of the nucleus, the most stable isobar is the one whose atomic number $Z_{A}$ is the one corresponding to the minimum mass, and can be found from the mass parabola or, by differentiating the mass equation with respect to $Z$, using the following final formula:

$$Z_{A}= \frac{\frac{A}{2}(1+\frac{(m_{n}-m_{p})c^2}{4a_{asym}})}{1+(\frac{a_{c}}{4a_{asym}})A^{2/3}}$$.

For odd-$A$ nuclei, there is a single most stable isobar, while for even-A, there are two equally probable most stable isobars.

My question is, if we were to determine the most stable isobar (in the case of even-A) using the formula above, it would only get us one value, but what about the other one, how could we determine it without graphing the parabola?

I can see from the example illustrated in my textbook for A=102, the two most stable isobars are at Z=44 and Z=46 which are 2 protons apart, and the formula gives the former, but I'm not sure if it's safe to say that they will always be 2 protons apart.